# How to add ManyToMany field in geojson serializer

Tags: django, gis, postgis, geodjango

After loading geospatial data into postgresql + postgis database, the goal is to return it in a view as **geojson** format.

**models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='groups')
```

**views.py**

```
def countries(request):
    queryset = Country.objects.annotate(json=AsGeoJSON('mpoly'))
    data = serializers.serialize(
        'geojson',
        queryset,
        geometry_field='mpoly',
        fields=('name', 'groups')
    )
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

The output geojson does not include nested **groups** for each country. How to add them into the features / properties field?

Comment: Probably if you need to serialize other models in the "root" model, it is better to work with the Django REST framework: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Django REST Framework is extremely slow compared to the code I shared.

Comment: @prodeda: typically if that is the case, it is due to inefficient querying (like prefetching the wrong way), or using DRF the wrong way. If it is the serialization process, then typically that is more due to Python not really aiming to be the most efficient language anyway, but trade that for programmer convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this by aggregating with [**`ArrayAgg`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg


def countries(request):
    queryset = Country.objects.annotate(
        json=AsGeoJSON('mpoly'), group_names=ArrayAgg('groups__name')
    )
    data = serializers.serialize(
        'geojson',
        queryset,
        geometry_field='mpoly',
        fields=('name', 'group_names'),
    )
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

But from the moment serialization becomes more complicated, you probably better use the [*Django REST framework* <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), which provides more sophisticated and complicated serialization.